# Permission default dialog not showing

Tags: android, android-permissions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shareitreplica">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shareitreplica"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation project(':library')
}
```

My code

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            System.out.println("Starting");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 111);
                System.out.println("Starting1");
            }
        }
```

I think this is the best way to get the permission from user. And the official doc also says this. But on running this code I am not prompted by the os for permission.

I get both the print lines after running the code.
I have Android Oreo version.

Answer (score 0):

The ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission has access level normal, it does not require the user to grant it at runtime.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) for reference.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I had no Idea about that. Anyways We have to request for it from my code and manifest file